# solving equations of density functions

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces, density-function

I have an engineering background, but not deep mathematics background. So, I am having difficulty proving an equation regarding density function as shown in the following problem, and I hope to get some help.

**- Problem statement:**
Given densities $f_1$ and $f_2$, set $g=f_1-f_2$. Then, $c=||g^+||=||g^-||=\frac{1}{2}||g||$ where $||\cdot||$ is L$1$-norm and $c > 0$.

For your reference, density function $f$ is $f \geq 0$, $||f||=1$, and $f \in L^1$ where $L^1$ is L$1$ space corresponding to measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, i.e., all real-valued measurable functions $f:X\rightarrow R$ s.t. $||f|| = \int_X |f(x)| \mu(dx) < \infty$.

**- My tries:**
I tried the followings, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Since $f_1 \in L^1$ and $f_2 \in L^1$, $g=f_1-f_2 \in L^1$, and, if we assume $||g^+||=||g^-||=c$ with $c > 0$,
\begin{align}
2c=||g^+|| + ||g^-|| &= ||(f_1-f_2)^+|| + ||(f_1-f_2)^-||\\
&= ||(f_1-f_2)^+ + (f_1-f_2)^-||\\
&= ||g||
\end{align}
where $f^+ := \max(0,f)$ and $f^- := \max(0,-f)$, and as a result, $f=f^+-f^-$. Also, one more useful property regarding L$1$ norm is that, if $f_1>0$, $f_2>0$, and $f_1,f_2 \in L^1$, then $||f_1 + f_2|| = ||f_1|| + ||f_2||$.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Looks correct. Did you already prove that $||g^+||=||g^-||$ or is this obvious to you?

Comment: @peaceful breeze No, I just assume they are the same, but I haven't proved it. Could you advise me for the proof on that part?

Comment: Sure, added an answer!

Answer (score 1):

To prove $\|g^+\|=\|g^-\|,$ we first use the fact that $\|f_1\|=\|f_2\|=1$ and that $f_1,f_2\ge0$ to get
\begin{align}
0=\|f_1\|-\|f_2\|&=\int_X |f_1| \ \mu(dx) - \int_X |f_2| \ \mu(dx) \\ 
&=\int_X \left(|f_1|-|f_2|\right) \ \mu(dx) \\ &= \int_X \left(f_1-f_2\right) \ \mu(dx).
\end{align}
But
$$\int_X \left(f_1-f_2\right) \ \mu(dx)=\int_X (f_1-f_2)^+ \ \mu(dx)-\int_X (f_1-f_2)^- \ \mu(dx)=0,$$ which implies that $$ \int_X (f_1-f_2)^+ \ \mu(dx)=\int_X (f_1-f_2)^- \ \mu(dx).$$
Since $(f_1-f_2)^+$ and $(f_1-f_2)^-$ are non-negative functions, we have that $\|g^+\|=\|g^-\|$.

The rest of the proof looks correct.

Comment: Great, thank you for the proof! It enlightened me :)

Comment: @H.C. You are welcome :)